# Extend OS partition during image restore

Tags: partitioning, cloning

We used [FOG](https://fogproject.org/) to create an image of Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop.
This image was made on a VM with 40 GB.

If we restore it on a new Dell E6520 with a hard drive of 250 GB.
Only 40 GB is allocated, just like the image was created.

Is there something like "extendospartition" in sysprep on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

In FOG there are several options to chose from:

- Multiple Partition Image - Single Disk (Non resizable)
- Single Disk - Resizable

After creating a image with "Single disk" "Resizable" it's alright.
The whole disk space is allocated.

It means FOG (1.20) is able to autoresize EXT4. Yay! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to download [GParted - Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php), burn it to a CD and boot the Dell that way.

If you're asking the question, it means you don't know what GParted is, so read the manual first and have it handy while you use GParted.

(It's partitioning software so if GPT, MBR, Primary, Extended , boot, diag, etc mean nothing to you, read the manual *twice*)  :-)